# Why XMLHttpRequest get aborted when I right click page then click 'Save As..' in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Here is the jsfiddle for test: http://jsfiddle.net/2LXrU/
Right click on the result panel and click on 'Save As...', you will see the result.

Anyone has idea what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that issuing the new request in a setTimeout will prevent the XHR from being cancelled.  I coded up a test here where you can try it out:

http://broofa.com/tests/SlowXHR.htm

Here's SendXHR.php (fwiw):

```
<?
sleep(2);
echo ", World";
```

With box unchecked, clicking "save as" stops the request cycle.
With box checked, "save as" doesn't interrupt the requests.

Comment: Hey robert, nice to see you here:) This is a fix for browser aborting all following up xhrs, but the current one is still being aborted tho. Nice test page :)